# Playing mutiple audio streams in Java

Tags: java, stream, javasound

I'm working on a voice chat mod for Minecraft. Everything is done so far, but I'm having problems playing the recorded sound. I can't use the Java Sound API for playing the sound because the write method of SourceDataLine blocks until everything is played. I also tried to make a thread for every player, but the write method can only be "play" one at a time.
I tried to use the paulscode library, but I also couldn't solve this problem (http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=1728.0)
Does anyone else have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
I will explain how i tried to play the sound packets and why i think this is not working:

so when the packet is received it should be played, every minecraft client has a PlayThread for every other player on the server.
The audio data will be added to a list using this function:

```
public static void addPacketToPlayer(String username, byte[] data, int length)
{
    getThreadOfPlayer(username).addPacket(data, length);
}
```

this function will create a new thread for each player.

```
public static PlayThread getThreadOfPlayer(String username)
{
    for(int zahl = 0; zahl < threads.size(); zahl++)
    {
        if(threads.get(zahl).username.equals(username))
            return threads.get(zahl);
    }
    PlayThread newThread = new PlayThread(username);
    newThread.start();
    threads.add(newThread);
    System.out.println("Created new thread for " + username + " currently "
    + PlayThread.threads.size() + " active");
    return newThread;
}
```

This is the constructor of the PlayThread:

```
public PlayThread(String username)
{
    this.username = username;

    data = new ArrayList<AudioData>();
    System.out.println("Start Playing sound");
    DataLine.Info info2 = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, VoiceChat.format);
    try { 
        source = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(VoiceChat.format);
        source.open(VoiceChat.format);
        source.start();     

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) { 
    }
}
```

The PlayThread checks if there are new AudioPackets and plays them:

```
public void run()
{
    while(mc.theWorld != null && !mc.isSingleplayer() && lastpacket < 10000)
    {
        if(data.size() > 0)
        {
            while(data.size() > 0)
            {
                AudioData audio = data.get(0);
                source.write(audio.data, 0, audio.length);
                data.remove(0);
                if(data.size() > 20)
                {
                    System.out.println("Remove all queued packets (" + data.size() + ") to make the delay smaller");
                    data.clear();
                }
            }
            source.drain();
            lastpacket = 0;
        }
        lastpacket++;
        try {
            sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    source.close();
    System.out.println("Stop playing sound");
    threads.remove(this);
}
```

This thread will close if it doesn't play any audiopacket for a time.

Here is the whole PlayThread class: http://pastebin.com/tB4tF4kj

The problem is that all threads are using the same SourceDataLine -> no audiopackets can be played at the same time, every thread has to wait until every other thread has played his audiopacket.
A server with 3 online people will always print out 'Remove all queued packets (20) to make the delay smaller' because the method write blocks it.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple lines to play multiple sounds (with a dedicated thread feeding each line). You will still be limited to what your audio hardware allows (e.g. at some point you will get a LineUnavailable when trying to play too many sounds).

Alternately, mix all the audio streams into a single PCM signal that can be fed to a single line. Mixing multiple PCM sounds isn't terribly difficult, although it may decrease audio quality slightly (shouldn't be a problem with a handful of audio streams).

Answer (score 0):

Check out TinySound, a Java library that allows mixing of tracks. I believe it is an open source project on github. It is pretty light-weight, works well.

As to blocking in audio, all SourceDataLines should be in their own threads! Are you doing that?

As to mixing, convert the bytes to PCM, then add (yes, simple arithmetic), then check for out of range numbers in the sums (may need to scale inputs a bit to keep all sounds within range--scaling can be done by multiplying each PCM value by a scaling fraction).

EDIT: Thanks for the comments and showing more code. I feel I don't yet fully grasp the problem--not clear to me the relevant issue(s) has been isolated.

Does a single chat input/output work okay? or does this block as well? What exactly is blocked? Other sounds or the running of the application itself?

If I'm reading your code correctly, then the thread is set up, data to be read is loaded via addPacket. But AudioData is not part of Java7 API, as far as I know. You are not using the method of reading audio that Oracle describes in their tutorial: [Capturing Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html)

I'm wondering, also, what happens when multiple threads access the "data" ArrayList. This seems like a potential for concurrency conflicts.

Given these various concerns, it is hard for me to comment on your implementation. I would start over and use a method more in line with the tutorial, and use TinySound for mixing. I'm sorry that I can't help more.

Comment: I using a thread for each player. I get the line by using this code:
http://pastebin.com/SD4qq4EX
So i looks like I'm always getting the same line :(

Comment: I looked, but I don't understand your code. If you are reading or capturing audio data, a TargetDataLine is more conventionally used. SourceDataLines are for output, not input, in my experience.

Comment: Yes, that is what i'm talking about. Here is the complete class of the playthread for each player:
http://pastebin.com/mHqYX0RH

Comment: Edits added to answer, in response to your last comment.

Comment: Do you have skype or could i send you an email? Because this is very hard to explain in this comment format.

Comment: Would that be an option Phil Freihofner?

Comment: If you have more you wish to explain, you should do so. Best to do it yourself, as a way of achieving personal clarity on the problem. Two benefits: likelihood of solving it yourself increases exponentially, others will be in a better position to offer insights.

Comment: yes :D, but these 'comments' haven't a line break, this would be very uncomfortable. I could explain this by using email or skype. That's what i wanted to ask for.

Comment: You can edit your original question to include the additional information. This is often done, and appropriate in this case, since you will be clarifying the situation.

Comment: So hope i could explain it to you :).

Comment: To recap: I'm not going to spend time with AudioData objects. I can't find them in the javax.sound.sampled api and have no wish to go down some undocumented cul de sac. Also, you are not acquiring the data via TargetDataLine, which is the only way I know. And if you are having problems with the single SoureDataLine, both answers suggested running multiple SourceDataLines concurrently or using a library like TinySound that mixes multiple sources down to a single SourceDataLine. You've stepped out of my expertise and I don't have the time to invest to learn undocumented stuff and make it work.

Comment: I'm very sorry, i forget to show the AudioData class (http://pastebin.com/Xn25hFva). Every client uses a TargetDataLine to record his microphone and send it to the server. The client recieves audiopackets from every client and should play them (that the PlayThread class).
I understand your answers, but i don't know where to start. I looked over the TinySound libary, but i saw any help in there. I searched PCM on google, but likewise i found nothing what could help me.
I will have to do some more researches, thanks for helping. I'm happy you tried to help me. Have a good day :).